# set width of chart, highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to set width of highcharts using percentage? Whenever the page is resized the charts should be responsive enough to fit the page size?

[One Solution](http://jsbin.com/anuqav/1/edit)

Question here is I have 3 charts which i need to display side by side and every-time the page is re-sized the 3 charts should scale up and use the screen size accordingly. Is it possible to doing using highcharts?

[Solution of this problem?](http://www.highcharts.com/jsbin/opuyav/2/edit)

Comment: Check this OUT for more correct solution http://jsfiddle.net/santoshgiridhar/ZrTux/19/

Comment: That was so helpful! I didn't realize I could just create a wrapper `div` and style it. I was trying to style the actual `div` into which the chart was being rendered...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Wrap your charts in a container and this will give you the flexibility to adjust the chart size when your screen changes.

Also provide a width to your wrapper and make it float to the left so that charts are placed side by side.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZrTux/9/

```
.chart-wrapper {
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 40%;
    position: relative;
    width: 45%;
}
```